# Python script to click a web page button

Tags: python, web

I have a python script that sends data to a django app using the requests library. Then the users switch to the web page and click a button which fetches an edit form to add some additional info

I want that immediately after requests recieves a status code 200 it will switch to the web page and click the button automatically, instead of the users doing it manually each time.

I looked into using Selenium but it seems like an overkill. Any thoughts how I can do this?

**edit**

The current process looks a little like this:

- user runs script on client side
- script runs and collects static data
- script sends data as post using requests
- the data is saved to a model called "Report", with a boolean field called "public" marked as False
- The user switches to the web app
- the user clicks a button that does an ajax call and fetches an edit form for that report (it knows you're the one who sent it by comparing the username of the logged in user)
- the user adds additional data and saves
- the field "public" changes to True and everyone can see the report.

Most of this is working, I just want the script to automatically switch to the web page and click the button instead of it being done manually. I know this is a little convoluted but I hope it explains things better

Also I'm using Windows and Chrome as my web browser

**Second Edit**

So I built a little demo to play around with. I created a file named 'test.html' which looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type='javascript/text' src='jquery.js' ></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <button id="button1"> Fake </button>
        <button id="button2"> Fake </button>
        <button id="button3"> Real </button>
    </div>


<script>
$(function() {
    $('#button3').on('click', function() {
          alert('you found it!');
    });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the only way to run the script is to click on the "real" button. Now I have written a python script which brings it up into the screen:

```
import win32gui

class Window(object):
    def __init__(self, handle):
        assert handle != 0
        self.handle = handle

    @classmethod
    def from_title(cls, title):
        handle = win32gui.FindWindow(title, None) or win32gui.FindWindow(None, title)
        return cls(handle)


chrome = Window.from_title('Test - Google Chrome')

win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(chrome.handle)
win32gui.SetFocus(chrome.handle)
```

Now how do I get it to replicate a button click done by the user? There probably is a way to do it graphically using coordinates but is that the *only way*? And how do you assure the button will always be at the same spot? Is there a better way than to use a button?

Comment: Send the appropriate POST request. Perhaps using Django's client.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're asking to do this client side? You don't want to edit the django app right?

Comment: I'm not following why you can't just do all of this using requests... perhaps if you post some of your script and show exactly where you are running into an issue?

Comment: Requests is working fine. But my users need to add some data after the generic data has been autocollected. Instead of switching the window and clicking the button the script should do it for them

Comment: Yes I want this client side

Comment: @yuvi: I think you need to be more specific: why does the user have a modal UI? Where is that coming from? A browser? A gtk application? If all your script is doing is passing data back and forth to a web server, can you explain what this UI is all about?

Comment: Some of the data is generic and is automatically collected. Then, the users go to the site and click a button that fetches a modal form and fill in the missing parts. I just want that the opening of the web page and button-click be a part of the script

Comment: To verify: you are looking for a way to, in a python script, open a browser window (which OS, which browser?) to a specific page with a form for the user to submit. The form will pop up a modal UI (an alert box, a window popup, an HTML/CSS-based "modal" box, you haven't specified here), which you want to have your script automatically close when the box appears. And your question is, "How should I do all of this?"

Comment: No. I know how to deal with browser opening, and the script doesn't need to deal with the form at all. It simply needs to click on a button as if it was done by the user. Everything that happens later is run by a jQuery script that listens for `$('button').on('click'…` and I know how to do that as well

Comment: @Mark Hilderth I made an edit, hope it clears things up a bit

Answer (score 1):

So all you want to do is automatically click a button when the page opens? I'm assuming you only want to auto-click in certain circumstances, so hide the javascript/jquery behind a conditional.

```
def your_view(request):
    # your standard processing
    auto_click = request.GET.get('auto_click', False)
    if auto_click is not False:
        auto_click = True
    render('yourtemplate.html', {'auto_click': auto_click })
```

Then, in your template:

```
{% if auto_click %}
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('yourbutton').click();
});
</script>
{% endif %}
```

When the user opens up the webpage, just append "?auto_click=1" to the URL, and you'll get the correct behaviour.

Comment: Some of the data has to be added manually. So I can't do everything using requests. I need that after the initial data is sent, the form on the web page will open up (I'm using bootstrap modal.js) and allow the users to do so. Right now they run the script, switch to the browser window and click on the fetch button manually

Comment: @yuvi Hmm, I've just updated but I think I've made an incorrect assumption. Is the webpage already open in the browser? I've assumed that the URL needs to load.

Comment: No heh that would've been easy. I want it to run on an already open tab

Comment: I can use win32gui to find the browser window and bring it up front but then what?

Comment: I have added an example of what I'm trying to achieve and my current progress. Will you kindly take a look?

Comment: @yuvi just offering up alternate suggestions since I don't know how you'd automate clicking a link without some kind of (usually expensive) automation tool but.. could you use client side javascript to poll django for when a new record is available and then show the modal?

Comment: I thought about that, using SetTimeout but I don't want users to wait for it to show up I want it to happen immediately. I mean I can tell it to run a check like that every second but wouldn't that put a lot of pressure on the server and make the site really slow?