# Python: Click by coordinate inside a window

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, pywin32

The goal of the program i'm trying to write is a bot that can click and play flash games and press keys inside a window webpage even when I do not have the window selected. My question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039789/python-script-to-click-a-web-page-button). What I want to know is how to use win32, selenium, and PIL to take screenshots, analyze the screenshots, and click and press buttons accordingly from the bot. I've looked through the win32api documentation and found little about how to click inside a window in the background.

If someone could give a link to someone who has done this before or just a little nudge in the right direction would be amazing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[pywinauto](https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/) is even simpler, but it may not recognize Flash controls. The code should just look a bit shorter:

```
import pywinauto
app = pywinauto.Application().connect(path='process_name.exe')
app.MainDialog.click_input(coords=(953, 656))
```

To check which controls are visible:

```
app.MainDialog.print_control_identifiers()
```

P.S. If you work with Python 3.x, [this clone](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto) is compatible with Py3.

Comment: How to click on treeview node using coordinates, click_input() does not seem to click or scroll till the element and clicks somewhere else randomly.

Comment: @Dev please describe your issue in a separate question with more details. It's not related to this answer, and if you believe it's a bug, please create issue on GitHub. I can't track comments under my random answers.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is detecting and interacting with images on screen, you might want to take a look at Sikuli. This is exactly what it does. Sikuli automates anything you see on the screen. It uses image recognition to identify and control GUI components. It is especially useful when there is no easy access to a GUI's internal or source code. More info [here](http://www.sikuli.org/).

Comment: I was really just looking to interact with flash objects but since there is no module that can help me with that I just had to resort to image analysis (PIL) and SendKeys (win32api).

`import win32com,win32api,win32gui,import ctypes

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_MAXIMIZE)
    sleep(3) 
    user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
    user32.SetCursorPos(953, 656)
    sleep(1)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)`

^works

Comment: It makes things alot easier and cleaner so yes Sikuli is great, however I was trying to see if there was a way to do it pure python.