# Converting TWB File to PDF

Tags: python, pdf, tableau-api

I am using Tableau 9.3 and Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

I have Tableau dashboards on Tableau server that are accessible via URL. For example: www.foo\tableau_dashboard1.twb

Is Python capable of converting these Tableau dashboards (twb file type) to PDF's?

I realize that Tableau dashboards can be converted using TabCMD https://community.tableau.com/message/186591

But I would like to do this in Python if possible.

Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible, and the easiest way is to pass required parameters (Dashboard name and credentials to the TabCmd) using python and TabCmd will do it for you.
For this you need to study how TabCmd creates pdf and then you will be able to write python.

Another way is that your python code will just access download_pdf link, as generally there is download_pdf link with tableau dashboards. [Here is a similar thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039789/python-script-to-click-a-web-page-button)

But if you think that you can write python code to read *.tbw file and create pdf then it will be too difficult and is like reinventing the wheel as Tableau already provides pdf generation.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could just append '?:format=pdf' to the URL

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/help.htm#embed_list.htm

Comment: yes python can be written to access url with `?:format=pdf` append and then download the pdf.